# Как подменить User-Agent?

Tags: javascript, chrome-extension

Как с помощью своего расширения подменить **User-Agent**?

Вот расширение

**content_script.js**

```
var fakeuseragent_code =  '(' + function() {
    'use strict';
    var navigator = window.navigator;
    var modifiedNavigator = Navigator.prototype;

    Object.defineProperties(modifiedNavigator, {
        userAgent: {
            value: "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 6_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/536.26 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0 Mobile/10A5376e Safari/8536.25",
            configurable: false,
            enumerable: true,
            writable: false
        },
        appVersion: {
            value: "5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 6_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/536.26 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0 Mobile/10A5376e Safari/8536.25",
            configurable: false,
            enumerable: true,
            writable: false
        },
        platform: {
            value: 'iPhone',
            configurable: false,
            enumerable: true,
            writable: false
        },
        vendor: {
            value: 'Apple, Inc.',
            configurable: false,
            enumerable: true,
            writable: false
        }
    });
} + ')();';

var s = document.createElement('script');
s.textContent = fakeuseragent_code;
document.documentElement.appendChild(s);
s.remove();
```

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    //
    "name": "fakeuseragent",
    "description": "fakeuseragent",
    "version": "0.0",
    //
    "content_scripts": [
        {
          "all_frames": true,
          "js": ["content_script.js"],
          "matches": ["*://*/*"],
          "run_at": "document_start"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Вывод консоли:**

[image]

Но это ни на что не влияет, то есть сайт не начинает определять вас как будто вы с айфона сидите.

**UPD.**

Всё таки на что-то влияет, плеер на ютубе меняется.

Comment: Вы смотрели как это сделано в других расширениях? Ну и не все сайты смотрят на UA — вы можете сколько угодно сообщать сайту UA айфона, но CSS и JS всё равно спалят, что у вас десктоп

Comment: Вам необходимо подменить UA в объекте браузера или для запросов, уходящих на сервер?

Comment: @Deliaz Ну очевидно для второго, так как мне нужно чтоб сайт думал что я с айфона сижу.

Comment: @myvvar это крайне не очевидно, ибо вы заходите не с той стороны. Воспользуйтесь [chrome.webRequest API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest) для перехвата и манипуляции заголовков запросов (в том числе user-agent).

Comment: @Deliaz chrome.webRequest будет работать только в background.js, реально ли сделать так чтоб из content_script.js работало? внедрить как-то код, или еще что...

Comment: @myvvar, в content-script нет такого API, оно вам и не нужно. То что вас интересует как-раз и выполняется на уровне background. Вы перехватываете все запросы (или по маске), меняете им UA, и отпускаете запрос дальше

Comment: @Deliaz а из content-script не реально такое сделать?

Comment: @myvvar все верно, не получится из cs